# ui-grid (ng-grid) with $http service data

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid, http-get

I am trying to fetch all the data from the server at once and then display the paginated data using ui-grid.

Here is what I did in my controller:

```
        $scope.myData = [];
        $http.get($rootScope.app.authApi + 'questions/' + selectedSubtopic.id).then(function (data) {
            $scope.myData = data;
        });
```

And in my html:

```
<div ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="myGrid"></div>
```

I keep getting this kind of error:

[image]

Comment: It maybe a version issue. Have you tried to upgrade both `ui-grid` and `angular` to the latest version ?

Comment: I have to stick to angular 1.3.15 for some reason. However I installed the latest version of the ui-grid. Should I downgrade? If yes, to what version.

Comment: There is this [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3677) on github. You probably return `{}` from your server instead of `[]`.

Comment: Code looks good. You should try to reproduce this in a plunkr for other people to help your specific case!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error.By looking at $http.get() result I found out that it's not an array but it's an object that has data as one of its members .So this should work :

```
 $scope.myData = [];
        $http.get($rootScope.app.authApi + 'questions/' + selectedSubtopic.id).then(function (result) {
            $scope.myData = result.data;
        });
```